# PHP getting current page url

Tags: php, url

I'm using this:

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

which will give me `/index.php` for example, how can I get it to not show the `/` so just `index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_url = substr($current_url, 1);
```

Substring removes the first character which is the forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) in PHP

```
<?php
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo basename($current_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there may be more than one slash ie. "/pages/test/page.php"

you should use

```
$current_url = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

or you can use

```
$current_url = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```